# Google-services apply plugin error, failed to resolve com.google.android.gms.11.0.4 and Error:(45,0)

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, firebase

Voila! Hopefully this will suffice for the error:(45,0) part!

[(Click for image) Check the error and the highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1ld3.png)

I'm guessing this problem is very simple and there's something i'm missing but this is my MyApplication's build.gradle code!

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
}

allprojects {
buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
}
```

And this is my App's build.gradle!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.teo.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:11.0.4'




testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Anyways.. The previous problem was about updating the google-services plugin or adding the `compile com.google.android.gms:10.2.0` or something like that and I tried adding the compile code to my App's build.gradle but the error stood it's place and there WAS a button where I could click to fix it and sync it but whenever I clicked it my Android Studio froze and then after a while it unfroze and nothing happened!

Hopefully I'm being stupid and there's a very simple fix for this problem! Thank you!

Edit:

I just added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'` into my build.gradle and the error changed to "`Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:11.0.4`" and I have that exact file in the build.gradle!!! Argh!!

This is the error log:

```
                                                      [ 11-30 20:29:26.163   
182:  182 E/         ]
                                                  invalid crash request of 
size 4 (from pid=18086 uid=0)
11-30 20:29:26.403 546-564/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: 
SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
11-30 20:29:26.437 18271-18271/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open 
handle to diag driver, error = 2 
11-30 20:29:26.438 18271-18271/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush 
failed, 9
11-30 20:29:26.439 18271-18271/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush 
failed, 9
11-30 20:29:26.468 18271-18273/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: 
smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6f969d4
11-30 20:29:26.558 18271-18275/? W/Sensors: 
sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
11-30 20:29:26.582 18271-18277/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug 
Config File missing in EFS!
11-30 20:29:40.605 1233-18282/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Failed network 
request due to no network connectivity: 
11-30 20:29:40.609 1233-18282/? E/ctxmgr: [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl 
fetch: network status=1
11-30 20:29:42.609 1808-1898/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process 
message: 10, size: 0
11-30 20:30:15.248 181-534/? D/MDnsDS: MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll timed 
out
1   1-30 20:30:15.248 181-534/? D/MDnsDS: Going to poll with pollCount 1
11-30 20:30:40.757 1233-18311/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Failed network 
request due to no network connectivity: 
11-30 20:30:40.761 1233-18311/? E/ctxmgr: [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl 
fetch: network status=1
 11-30 20:30:42.929 1808-1898/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process 
 message: 10, size: 0

                                                  [ 11-30 20:31:17.387   
182:  182 E/         ]
                                                  invalid crash request of 
size 4 (from pid=18271 uid=0)
11-30 20:31:17.602 546-564/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: 
SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
11-30 20:31:17.626 18340-18340/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open 
handle to diag driver, error = 2
11-30 20:31:17.626 18340-18340/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush 
failed, 9
11-30 20:31:17.627 18340-18340/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush 
failed, 9
11-30 20:31:17.662 18340-18342/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: 
smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6fe49d4
11-30 20:31:17.749 18340-18344/? W/Sensors: 
sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
11-30 20:31:17.771 18340-18346/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug 
Config File missing in EFS!
11-30 20:31:22.729 1152-18348/? I/BgTaskExecutorImpl: Starting EXCLUSIVE 
background task now_calendar_update.
11-30 20:31:23.142 1808-1927/? W/bt-btm: Stopping oneshot timer
11-30 20:31:40.867 1233-18352/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Failed network 
request due to no network connectivity: 
11-30 20:31:40.872 1233-18352/? E/ctxmgr: [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl 
fetch: network status=1
11-30 20:31:43.248 1808-1898/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process 
message: 10, size: 0
11-30 20:32:41.057 1233-18353/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Failed network 
request due to no network connectivity: 
11-30 20:32:41.065 1233-18353/? E/ctxmgr: [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl 
fetch: network status=1
11-30 20:32:43.558 1808-1898/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process 
message: 10, size: 0
11-30 20:32:45.904 26912-27049/? I/PlayCommon: [1837] 
com.google.android.play.a.h.e(248): Preparing logs for uploading
11-30 20:32:45.905 26912-27049/? I/PlayCommon: [1837] 
com.google.android.play.a.h.e(252): No file ready to send

                                           [ 11-30 20:33:08.722   182:  182 
E/         ]
                                           invalid crash request of size 4 
(from pid=18340 uid=0)
11-30 20:33:08.913 546-564/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: 
SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
11-30 20:33:08.948 18397-18397/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open 
handle to diag driver, error = 2  
11-30 20:33:08.949 18397-18397/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush 
failed, 9
11-30 20:33:08.950 18397-18397/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush 
failed, 9
11-30 20:33:08.974 18397-18399/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: 
smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6f219d4
11-30 20:33:09.052 18397-18401/? W/Sensors: 
sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
11-30 20:33:09.073 18397-18403/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug 
Config File missing in EFS!
11-30 20:33:14.493 26912-26953/? I/PlayCommon: [1790] 
com.google.android.play.a.h.e(248): Preparing logs for uploading
11-30 20:33:14.593 26912-26953/? I/PlayCommon: [1790] 
com.google.android.play.a.h.a(470): Connecting to server: 
https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
11-30 20:33:14.599 26912-26953/? E/PlayCommon: [1790] 
com.google.android.play.a.h.a(500): Failed to connect to server: 
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": 
No address associated with hostname
11-30 20:33:41.168 1233-18309/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Failed network 
request due to no network connectivity: 
11-30 20:33:41.176 1233-18309/? E/ctxmgr: [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl 
fetch: network status=1
```

I'm pretty sure the real error is near the end!! Please help

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

Comment: That worked except now I have the original error! It says "Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:11.0.4" when it's right there in the build.gradle and it looks like it should function correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:11.0.4'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:11.0.4'
```

All dependencies must be the same version.